# datadog python data export

Tags: export, datadog

I want to be able to export raw data from Datadog.
the idea is to support higher level of analysis in regards to the metrics captured, upstream from the Datadog UI.

the metrics query API, allows only to query re-aggregated data according to bins that cannot be explicitly set. it does not allow to either access the raw data, or to explicitly define the terms for the aggregation.

the log option in Datadog does not seems to be fully supported through the API (or has limited documentation)

I am interested in any upstream integration options from DataDog to another Data client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this question was asked, Datadog has since added functionality to the Logs and Metrics Query endpoints.

For Metric queries, see here for how you might set different aggregations or bucketing to select specific time series: https://docs.datadoghq.com/api/v1/metrics/#query-timeseries-points

To emit Logs to a long-term archive on a cloud storage provider, such as AWS S3, Azure Storage, or Google Cloud Storage.
See more details here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/archives/

Once the logs are on a long-term storage, you can process them via a mechanism of your choice, for example using Amazon Athena to query the log data.
See the format of the archive structure and data format here:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/logs/archives/#format-of-the-archives